# Error: Undefined Method `Truncate' For Nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

***Update***
I fixed it by removing the descritpion truncate tags and HTML-Safe tags. Not exactly what I wanted because I still need the function but at last the site is up and I can figure out what the issue is.

I was trying to truncate the description of a blog post but it didn't work so I deleted everything having to do with truncate. My rails app works on development but it doesn't show the homepage in the heroku production environment even though the rest of the pages do like /blog and /articles. Site link: https://www.xrloaded.com  Link to my repo: https://github.com/maxrosales83/findXRJobs

I want to eliminate the error and have the homepage loading again.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

I'm not sure why the error is showing. I looked around for answers but nothing made sense.
Here is my articles model:

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user , :optional => true
  mount_uploader :blogimage, AvatarUploader
    def admin?
      admin
    end
end
```

Here is my articles controller:

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_article, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]



    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

    def index
        @articles = Article.limit(3).order("id desc")
        @secondrow = Article.limit(3).offset(3).order("id desc")
    end

    def create
      #render plain: params[:article].inspect
      @article = Article.new(article_params)
        if @article.save
            flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully created"
            redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update

      if @article.update(article_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Article was updated"
       redirect_to article_path(@article)
      else
       flash[:notice] = "Article was not updated"
       render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def show

    end

    def destroy

      @article.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Article was deleted"
      redirect_to articles_path
    end
    private
        def article_params
            params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description, :blogimage)
        end
        def set_article
            @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

Articles Index view:

```
<!-- page header (title, etc) -->
   <div class="main-header">
     <section class="hero">
   <div class="hero-body">
     <div class="container">
       <div class="has-text-centered">
         <!-- header && subheader -->
         <h1 class="title is-1 is-spaced">XR Loaded Blog</h1>

         <!-- end of header && subheader -->

         <!-- header nav content -->
         <div class="nav-center">
       <a class="nav-item" href="https://www.facebook.com/xrloaded/">
         <span class="icon">
           <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
         </span>
       </a>
       <a class="nav-item" href="https://www.instagram.com/xrloadedapp/">
         <span class="icon">
           <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
         </span>
       </a>
         </div>
         <!-- end of header nav content -->
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
     </section>
   </div>
   <!-- end page header -->


       <!-- page content -->

       <div class="main-content">

           <div class="container">
                   <!-- start of posts -->

               <div class="columns has-text-centered">
               <!-- start of post -->
                   <% @articles.each do |article| %>
                   <div class="column is-4" >

                       <div class="card">

                         <!-- image for post -->
                         <div class="card-image">
                       <figure class="image is-4by3">

                           <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>

                           <% if !article.blogimage.file.nil? %>
                               <%= link_to image_tag(article.blogimage_url(:thumb),:class => "image is-5by3"), article_path(article) %>
                           <% end %>

                       </figure>
                         </div>
                         <!-- end of image for post -->

                         <!-- post header -->
                         <div class="card-content-header">
                       <h4 class="title is-4"><a href="post.html"><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></a></h4>
                       <%= link_to article.description, article_path(article) %>
                         </div>
                         <!-- end of post header -->

                         <!-- post content -->
                         <div class="card-content">
                           <div class="content">
                             <div class="nav-center">
                               <a class="nav-item" href="">
                                 <span class="icon">
                               <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                 </span>
                               </a>
                               <a class="nav-item" href="">
                                 <span class="icon">
                               <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                 </span>
                               </a>
                               <a class="nav-item" href="">
                                 <span class="icon">
                               <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                 </span>
                               </a>

                             </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end of post content -->

                       <!-- post footer -->

                       <!-- end of post footer -->
                         </div>

                       </div>



                   </div>
                   <% end %> 


               <!-- end of post -->
               </div>
               <div class="columns has-text-centered">
               <!-- start of post -->
                   <% @secondrow.each do |article| %>
                   <div class="column is-4" >

                       <div class="card">

                         <!-- image for post -->
                         <div class="card-image">
                       <figure class="image is-4by3">
                           <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %>

                         <img src="http://placehold.it/700x500" alt="Image">
                       </figure>
                         </div>
                         <!-- end of image for post -->

                         <!-- post header -->
                         <div class="card-content-header">
                       <h4 class="title is-4"><a href="post.html"><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></a></h4>
                       <%= link_to article.description, article_path(article) %>
                         </div>
                         <!-- end of post header -->

                         <!-- post content -->
                         <div class="card-content">
                           <div class="content">
                             <div class="nav-center">
                               <a class="nav-item" href="">
                                 <span class="icon">
                               <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                 </span>
                               </a>
                               <a class="nav-item" href="">
                                 <span class="icon">
                               <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                 </span>
                               </a>
                               <a class="nav-item" href="">
                                 <span class="icon">
                               <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                 </span>
                               </a>

                             </div>
                           </div>
                           <!-- end of post content -->

                       <!-- post footer -->

                       <!-- end of post footer -->
                         </div>

                       </div>



                   </div>
                   <% end %> 


               <!-- end of post -->
               </div>



               <!-- end of posts -->   
           </div>

       </div>
     <!-- pagination -->
     <div class="pagination-style-custom">
   <div class="container has-text-right">
     <a class="button is-button-grey pagination-next">Show More Posts</a>
   </div>
     </div>
     <!-- end of pagination -->
   </div>
   <!-- end of page content -->
```

Schema File:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20200112211550) do

  create_table "ahoy_events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "visit_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "properties"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.index ["name", "time"], name: "index_ahoy_events_on_name_and_time"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_ahoy_events_on_user_id"
    t.index ["visit_id"], name: "index_ahoy_events_on_visit_id"
  end

  create_table "ahoy_visits", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "visit_token"
    t.string "visitor_token"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "ip"
    t.text "user_agent"
    t.text "referrer"
    t.string "referring_domain"
    t.text "landing_page"
    t.string "browser"
    t.string "os"
    t.string "device_type"
    t.string "country"
    t.string "region"
    t.string "city"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.string "utm_source"
    t.string "utm_medium"
    t.string "utm_term"
    t.string "utm_content"
    t.string "utm_campaign"
    t.string "app_version"
    t.string "os_version"
    t.string "platform"
    t.datetime "started_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_ahoy_visits_on_user_id"
    t.index ["visit_token"], name: "index_ahoy_visits_on_visit_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "blogimage"
  end

  create_table "jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "url"
    t.string "job_type"
    t.string "location"
    t.string "job_author"
    t.boolean "remote_ok"
    t.string "apply_url"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "avatar"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "stripe_id"
    t.string "card_brand"
    t.string "card_last4"
    t.string "card_exp_month"
    t.string "card_exp_year"
    t.datetime "expires_at"
    t.boolean "admin"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Routes file:

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  resources :jobs do
    get :search #creates new path for search feature
  end

  resources :articles
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'jobs#index'
  get '/info' => 'pages#info'
  get '/blog' => 'articles#index'
  get '/privacy' => 'pages#privacy'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  get '/emailsignup'  => 'emailapi#index'
  post '/emailapi/subscribe'=> 'emailapi#subscribe'



end
```

Comment: What you want i.e. what you need help for? is not clear. Please make that clear.

Comment: @ARK Thank you for replying. I updated the post to state that I'm trying to show my homepage again which shows the error.